# slow ng-repeat processing of array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to iterate over an array of objects:

```
$scope.items = {key1: val1, key2: val2, keyx: valx}
```

In my template I use ng-repeat in a table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td> {{item.key1}} </td>
    <td> {{item.key2}} </td>
    <td> {{item.keyx}} </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that it is terribly slow. I tried this in both v1.0.8 and v1.2.5, same result. Only when I have just one table cell it becomes rather speedy, but as soon as I add over 5-6 item keys then it takes seconds to load. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: how many rows are you talking about?

Comment: 50 rows, without limiting the issue is amplified. Ideally I would like 100 (big monitors).

Comment: here's `10x100` , goes quick , must be something in your filtering, or waiting on ajax?  http://jsfiddle.net/PJ4FP/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">
  <td> {{key}} </td>
  <td> {{value}} </td>
</tr>
```